# How can I convert a String date with full month names to a Date object in java?

Tags: java

How can I convert dates with full month names into a Date object in Java? Here's a sample date that I need to convert: 6 December 2002.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 String str = "6 December 2002";
 DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
 Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(str);
```

- [Here is working IDE One demo](http://ideone.com/MJX27)

**Must See**

- [API Doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMMM yyyy", Locale.US);
Date d = sdf.parse("6 December 2002");
System.out.println(d);
```